# Using jQuery to restyle page depending on window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I currently have a JavaScript file that I'm using to fix the navigation on a website I've built. The code is by no means 'DRY', though, and I'd like to fix that issue.

```
//fixing the nav dropdowns for mobile


//concrete and joint repair dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggle").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.target'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggle").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.target'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".target").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.target'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end concrete and joint repair dropdown section





//primers and sealers dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleTwo").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetTwo'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleTwo").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetTwo'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetTwo").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetTwo'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end primers and sealers dropdown section


//high build coatings dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleThree").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetThree'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleThree").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetThree'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetThree").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetThree'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end high build coatings dropdown section




//self levelers and overlays dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleFour").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetFour'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleFour").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetFour'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetFour").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetFour'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end self levelers and overlays dropdown section




//vertical coatings dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleFive").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetFive'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleFive").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetFive'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetFive").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetFive'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end vertical coatings dropdown section



//performance topcoats dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleSix").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetSix'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleSix").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetSix'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetSix").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetSix'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end performance topcoats dropdown section


//elastomerics dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleSeven").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetSeven'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleSeven").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetSeven'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetSeven").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetSeven'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end elastomerics dropdown section


//cleaning products dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleEight").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetEight'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleEight").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetEight'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetEight").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetEight'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end cleaning products dropdown section



//installations dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleNine").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetNine'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleNine").click.hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetNine'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetNine").click.hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetNine'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end installations dropdown section


//additional products dropdown section

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);


    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();

        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggleTen").click(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetTen'),
                $toggle = $(this);

            $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {

            //if the window is less than 990px wide then flyout on hover..

            $("#toggleTen").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetTen'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetTen").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.targetTen'),
                $toggle = $(this);

                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();
    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});

//end additional products dropdown section


//end fixing the nav dropdowns for mobile
```

Comment: I've currently changed it to be if (windowsize <= 990) & else if (windowsize >= 991). I believe this solves it.

Comment: Is your checkWidth function also responsible for styling things based on the width or just checking the width?

Comment: It is only used for checking the width. Depending on what your referring to by 'style'. When my checkWidth runs it looks to see what the window width is. If it is smaller then the nav opens on click. If the window width is larger then nav items open on hover.

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot achieve this with only CSS and mediaqueries?

Comment: Typically I would say yes, however, I'm using a bootstrap wire frame and the authors have made a mess of the nav. I contacted them and they didn't even have a solution. So it was faster to simply override the settings with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just fix it, the lesson to learn here is about parametrizing functions.

When you find yourself with lots of repeated code where only a small number of values change, you should wrap it up as a function and instead supplying the changing values as arguments.

For example, a large part of the code above is the duplication of this kind of code.

```
$('#toggleOne').hover(function() {
  var $target = $('.targetOne');
  $target.toggle();
});
```

Instead, you can write

```
function toggle(hoverElement, toggleElement) {
  $(hoverElement).hover(function() {
    var $target = $(toggleElement);
    $target.toggle();
  });
}
```

Then rather than writing it all out again, simply call the function and adjust those values.

```
toggle('#toggleOne', '.targetOne');
// ...
toggle('#toggleTwo', '.targetTwo');
```

Comment: Dan, I utilized your method and everything seems to work great. However,  I ran the function within the 'if' statement and then within the 'else if' statement separately for each different window size and the 'else if' is now over riding the 'if' statement. Please see the JsFiddle of the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cboardway/h0eb8aLq/   any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your ids and classes to use numerica values such as `.target-1` for instance... then just create a for loop to iterate with it. Note: You only need to call on document ready once:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Optimalisation: Store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);
    var limit = 10;
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize < 990) {
            //if the window is less than 990px wide then turn on flyout on click..
            $("#toggle-"+i).click(function(){
            var $target = $('.target-'+i),
                $toggle = $(this);
                $target.toggle();
            });
        } 


        else if (windowsize > 990) {
            $("#toggleSeven").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.target-'+i),
                $toggle = $(this);
                $target.toggle();
            }); 

            $(".targetSeven").hover(function(){
            var $target = $('.target-'+i),
                $toggle = $(this);
                $target.toggle();
            }); 

        }
    }
    for(var i =0; i <= limit; i++) {
        checkWidth(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call another function with the value of the width resolved by the checkWidth function then you will be able to style it based on the width. So something like this.

```
$(window).resize(checkWidth);

Function checkWidth () {

var width = $(window).width();

//example function call

stylePage(width);

}

function stylePage (width) {

//page styling code goes here

If(width < X) {

//style for smaller devices or whatever
}
```

Comment: Aaaah I see where you going with this. I took this into account and realized that I needed to call my $(window).resize(checkWidth); outside of my $document.ready(); function and it seems to have fixed the issue. See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Cboardway/h0eb8aLq/1/   the jsfiddle has my new code that I revised after looking at Dan Prince's repsonse above. Though with this code I am still having the issue of the 'if else' statement over riding the 'if' statement. Which makes it fly out on hover no matter what the screen size.